# Contour plot in square points

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I have a 3 data sets, X,Y,Z which are my axes and my data respectively. They are well defined, i.e.
len(X) = len(Y) = len(Z) = len(Z[i]) = N for i in range(0,N).

I would like to make a similar to a contourf plot (I already made it), but using **discrete axes**, like a "contour squares", where each square (x,y) has a color given by the Z value (which is a float value).

So far I'm using the contourf(X,Y,Z), but it makes some interpolations that I don't want, I need a better visualization with squares.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What you are describing sounds like `imshow` to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use **matshow** or **imshow** plotting functions.

An important argument here is the *interpolation* one.
Check this [example from the matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/image_interp.html) to see some examples.

By using *matshow()*, keyword arguments are passed to *imshow()*.
*matshow()* sets defaults for *origin*, *interpolation* (**='nearest'**), and *aspect*.

here is an example from my own work...

```
# level, time and conc are previously read from a file

X,Y=[level,time]   
Z=conc.transpose() # Create the data to be plotted

cax = matshow(Z, origin='lower', vmin=0, vmax=500)
    # I am telling all the Z values above 500 will have the same color
    # in the plot (if vmin or vmax are not given, they are taken from
    # the input’s minimum and maximum value respectively)
grid(True)
cbar = colorbar(cax)
```

...which returns this plot:

[image: perfil vertical]